# What word means "the sights, things, and activities that are special" in a place?

Tags: single-word-requests

Typically, each city or region has its own special sights, cuisine, crafts, festivals, and activities. These need not necessarily be fully unique to a place, but might be things which local people will hope tourists will take note of. Is there a single word which can refer to these "sights, foods, activities" altogether?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would call these *attractions*

> [***attraction***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/attraction?q=attraction) : *n.  A thing or place that draws visitors by providing something of interest or pleasure*

Comment: I'd recommend this too, but "features" may be a viable alternative

Comment: I think "highlights" would often fit, too.

Answer (score 2):

*Local color* could work here to refer to the things that give a place its personality.

> local color
>   n.
>   1. The interest or flavor of a locality imparted by the customs and sights peculiar to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

- atmosphere
- ambiance
- environment
- aura
- vibe

Of these terms, I would use vibe as the all-encompassing term.

Answer (score 1):

Flavour.

[Definition of flavour](http://www.beedictionary.com/definition/flavour)

Answer (score 1):

*Culture* might be applicable but it depends in what context you’re using the word. From Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> culture, n.
>
> The distinctive ideas, customs, social behaviour, products, or way of life of a particular nation, society, people, or period. Hence: a society or group characterized by such customs, etc.

It can be used in many different ways:

> cultural festival n.
>
> A festival featuring arts and events specific to a particular culture, esp. one celebrating and promoting that culture in a wider public context.